# How can you get thread count of running process in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, process, threads

I have a multi threaded C# application and I want to see active threads of that process while running. Where can I see it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Open Task Manager (for example, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>) and go to the Processes tab.

From the menu, select `View` > `Select Columns...` and enable `Threads`.

[image]

You can also achieve the same thing with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

Comment: Process Explorer has an option to display the total thread count in the status bar.

Comment: Thank you ! But on my computer, Threads column show sometime a number really bigger than my total number of threads .... (example firefox 83 threads ....) What does that mean ?

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 10

```
Task manager -> Details -> (right click) Select columns -> (check) Threads
```

[image]